# Sliding divs only when clicking on buttons within the divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use JQuery to slide a div with some content to the left and make the one from the right appear in the place of the previous one.

I already made it work but the thing is, it only works when I click on the div (box) that contains all the content.
I want to change that so it only changes when I click on the buttons within those divs (boxes).

Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/Msiric/g8Lne34o/1/

So what I want to do is this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.buttons').click(function() {
    $('.box').animate({
        left: '-125%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $('.box').css('left', '150%');
        $('.box').appendTo('#inputform');
    });
    $('.box').next().animate({
        left: '25%'
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

Notice the `$('.buttons).onclick` instead of `$('.box').onclick`.
When I do this the code doesn't work as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind the event to `buttons` and animate the boxes `using $(this).closest(".box")`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.buttons').click(function() {

    $(this).closest(".box").animate({
      left: '-125%'
    }, 500, function() {
      $(this).css('left', '150%');
      $(this).appendTo('#inputform');
    });

    $(this).closest(".box").next().animate({
      left: '25%'
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
#inputform {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 300px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 25%;
  margin-left: -25%;
}

#box1 {
  background-color: #333;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: #333;
  left: 150%;
}

#box3 {
  background-color: #333;
  left: 150%;
}

#box4 {
  background-color: #333;
  left: 150%;
}

#box5 {
  background-color: #333;
  left: 150%;
}

#requestbox {
  width: 75%;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3.1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: medium;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  resize: none;
}

#requestbox:focus {
  height: 100px;
}

.forms {
  width: 75%;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3.1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: medium;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  resize: none;
}

.buttons {
  display: block;
  width: 18%;
  height: 31px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(70, 42, 24), rgb(244, 117, 33));
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: medium;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputform">
  <div id="box1" class="box">
    <textarea placeholder="Some text" id="requestbox" class="forms"></textarea>
    <button id="next" class="buttons">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div id="box2" class="box">
    <textarea placeholder="Some text" id="setbox" class="forms"></textarea>
    <button id="set" class="buttons">Set</button>
  </div>
  <div id="box3" class="box">
    <textarea placeholder="Some text" id="attachbox" class="forms"></textarea>
    <button id="attach" class="buttons">Attach</button>
  </div>
  <div id="box4" class="box">
    <textarea placeholder="Some text" id="confirmbox" class="forms"></textarea>
    <button id="confirm" class="buttons">Confirm</button>
  </div>
  <div id="box5" class="box">
    <textarea placeholder="Some text" id="publishbox" class="forms"></textarea>
    <button id="publish" class="buttons">Publish</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding to this comment, OP should also look into [caching jQuery objects](https://pseudosavant.com/blog/2014/01/30/js-101-cache-your-selectors/). Instead of doing `$(this)` all the time, save it to a variable `var $this = $(this)` and use that instead. (And other objects as well)

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro Valid point! But there two separate instances of `$(this)` as inner `$(this)` is for animating object.

Comment: True, a better solution would be to cache the `.box` like @RenzoCC did in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

change like this, add the event listener to the button [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/s4fbhnkb/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.buttons').click(function() {
        var $box = $(this).closest('.box');
    $box.animate({
        left: '-125%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#inputform');
    });

    $box.next().animate({
        left: '25%'
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Really nice you included cache in your code, line 7 and 8 can also use the cached `$box`

Answer (score -2):

Did you try using the bootstrap?

```
    <div class="row" "><!-- Sliding image row -->
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators"><!-- Indicators -->
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol><!-- /Indicators -->
            <div class="carousel-inner"><!-- Wrapper -->
              <div class="item active" ><!-- item1 -->
                <img src="images/slide1.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
              </div><!-- /item1 -->
              <div class="item"><!-- item2 -->
                <img src="images/slide2.jpg" style="width:100%" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">                      
                </div>
              </div><!-- /item2 -->
            </div><!-- /Wrapper -->
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control " href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div><!-- /mycarousel -->
        </div><!-- /col-xs-12 -->
    </div><!-- /Sliding image row -->
```

you can put your button instead of the part that puts an arrow for the next slide.

Comment: Why use bootstrap for something so simple?

Comment: I don't think that bootstrap is complicated, it is just helping with some ready-made classes

Comment: I wasn't saying that bootstrap is complicated, just that it's not the best choice for every problem, this one specifically.